# How can I show when users were last active based on statistics?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database that stores the datetime from getdate() when they log into the system.

I want to do a select that shows ones that have been active in the last 10mins as 'active now' and for all the rest, say how long ago they were active e.g. 3 days or 3hrs.

I have no idea how to do the second part of that.

This is what I have done to get the active users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, 'Active now'
FROM dbo.Users UP
INNER JOIN Portal.dbo.UserStatistics US
ON US.UserID = UP.UserID
INNER JOIN Portal.dbo.Pages
ON pages.id = US.PageID
WHERE US.DateTimeLastUpdated >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, 
CASE when US.DateTimeLastUpdated >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate()) then 'Active now' else cast(datediff(h,getdate(), US.DateTimeLastUpdated) as varchar) end
FROM dbo.Users UP
INNER JOIN Portal.dbo.UserStatistics US
ON US.UserID = UP.UserID
INNER JOIN Portal.dbo.Pages
ON pages.id = US.PageID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement with a group by clause:

```
SELECT 
   FirstName, 
   LastName, 
   case when max(US.DateTimeLastUpdated) >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate()) then
          'Active now'
        when max(US.DateTimeLastUpdated) >= dateadd(day, -2, getdate()) then
          'Active 3 days'
   ...
   end as [last viewed]
FROM 
   dbo.Users UP
INNER JOIN 
   Portal.dbo.UserStatistics US
                ON US.UserID = UP.UserID
INNER JOIN 
   Portal.dbo.Pages
                ON pages.id = US.PageID
GROUP BY 
   FirstName, 
   LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate to get the latest access per user, and then work with that, so something a little like:

```
SELECT      up.FirstName, 
            up.LastName, 
            CASE 
                WHEN MAX(US.DateTimeLastUpdated) >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate()) THEN 'Now'
                ELSE CAST(MAX(DATEDIFF(H, US.DateTimeLastUpdated, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) + ' hours ago' 
            AS LastActive

FROM        dbo.Users UP

INNER JOIN  Portal.dbo.UserStatistics US
    ON      US.UserID = UP.UserID

INNER JOIN  Portal.dbo.Pages
    ON      pages.id = US.PageID

GROUP BY    up.FirstName, 
            up.LastName
```

Comment: This could potentially work but there are issues with the code I don't know how to fix. It days H is not a datepart so I added hh, then it complained about the 'as varchar' so i removed it, then incorrect syntax with a missing bracket and then incorrect syntax near from which I can't fix.

Comment: I got your example to work but the values it returns are always around this (give or take a few hours) 1272 hours ago

Comment: @connersz I've rebalanced my brackets, but you could add `MAX(US.DateTimeLastUpdated)` to the query to debug it yourself, to see if the values are meaningful...